# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, thinking-sphinx

I am facing the following issue on Mac when I run `rake ts:index` for Thinking Sphinx indexing:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib`

I am using mysql version 8.0.13 for osx10.13 on x86_64.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @ray Question was, how can this issue be resolved? The solution is written in the answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Insalling unixodbc on Mac resolved this for me.

```
brew install unixodbc
```

Answer (score 14):

In addition to

```
brew install unixodbc
```

you can also install the mssql drivers after this with the following brew instructions:

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install msodbcsql mssql-tools
```

After this I was able to use "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" in python.