# How to connect to MySQL Workbench Database using PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database through Python using PyCharm. I am using the following code.

```
from errno import errorcode

import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import os

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.getcwd()

team_df = pd.read_excel('sampledata.xlsx', sheet_name='Team')

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                              database='SoccerDatabase',
                              user='root',
                              password='')
if cnx.is_connected():
    print("Connection Established")
cnx.close()
```

However, I am not able to connect and getting the following error:

```
import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bansarivadgama/Desktop/integrationfactory/DataModellingIntegrationFactory/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 428, in <module>
    ODBC_API = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libodbc.so')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 454, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: dlopen(libodbc.so, 0x0006): tried: 'libodbc.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibodbc.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libodbc.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libodbc.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libodbc.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bansarivadgama/Desktop/integrationfactory/DataModellingIntegrationFactory/dataimport.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pypyodbc
  File "/Users/bansarivadgama/Desktop/integrationfactory/DataModellingIntegrationFactory/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 440, in <module>
    raise OdbcNoLibrary('ODBC Library is not found. Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?')
pypyodbc.OdbcNoLibrary: 'ODBC Library is not found. Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone help me out figuring the solution ?

Comment: it seems like the issue is related to the ODBC library not being found. You can resolve this by installing the unixODBC library

Comment: pyodbc is already installed @JohnAtughara

Comment: Make sure you have the correct driver path specified in your code. In your case, the driver path should be driver='/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib'

Comment: Check if the driver is listed correctly in your odbcinst.ini file. It should look like this:
Copy[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
UsageCount=1

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302793/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-unixodbc-lib-libodbc-2-dylib) helped to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is resolved by installing the following library:

```
brew install unixodbc
```